# <p:treeTable> duplicates rows

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a set of classes that have to-many relationships to themselves. They are used to maintain a hierarchical tree structure.

I am attempting to use primefaces's TreeTable component to display that hierarchy. I created a TreeNode implementation by inheriting from DefaultTreeNode:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TreeNavigationController implements Serializable 
{
    public static class GroupNode extends DefaultTreeNode implements Serializable
    {
    private List<TreeNode> childNodes = null;

    public TickerNode(Object data, TreeNode descriptionNode) {
        super(data, descriptionNode);
    }

    public List<Object> subgroups() {
        // fetch subgroups from backend
        ...
    }

    @Override
        public int getChildCount() {
        return getSubgroups().size();
    }

    @Override
        public List<TreeNode> getChildren() {
        if (childNodes==null) {
        childNodes = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
        for (TickerGroup g : getSubgroups())
            childNodes.add(new TickerNode(g,this));
        }           
        return childNodes;
    }
    }

    public TreeNavigationController() {
    root = new DefaultTreeNode("root", null);
    // fetch top groups from backend
    List<Object> topGroups = ...
    for (Object g : topGroups) 
        GroupNode gn = new GroupNode(g,root);
    }
}
```

The XHTML is straightforward:

```
<p:treeTable id="treetable" value="#{treeNavigationController.root}" var="node" binding="#{treeNavigationController.treeTable}">
    <p:column style="width:32%">
        <h:outputText value="#{node.label}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:4%">
        <p:commandLink  title="Klick me" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{node}" target="#treeNavigationController.selectedGroup}" />
        </p:commandLink>
    </p:column>
</p:treeTable>
```

All of this works well. When the tree expands another level, the getChildren() is called and so on. There is only one hitch: all rows (except for the top rows) are **duplicated**!

I verified that the data source returns the correct objects only once and the GroupNode objects are also only created once per object. Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DefaultTreeNode's constructor already adds the node to the children. Maybe it helps someone else avoid the same trouble.